# Не могу получить значение через DISTINCT?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет не работает вот такой запрос.

Select *, DISTINCT title From product where brend = 'sauflon'

Пишет ошибку, что делаю не так?

Нужно получить все столбцы, но только что бы title не повторялся.

Answer (score 3):

пишу по памяти

```
SELECT *
FROM product
GROUP BY title
HAVING brend = 'sauflon'
```

Comment: уау, хорош, работает!

Comment: Это только кажется на первый взгляд. Во-первых,     `select * from product where brend = 'sauflon' group by title;`  Во-вторых, из тех строк у которых одинаковый title будет выбрана произвольная, если нужна определенность, то см http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html

Answer (score 0):

Укажите либо * либо перечислите нужные поля. И слово distinct после select должно идти. Чтобы не повторялся title укажите условие в запросе, либо сгруппируйте. Если есть строки с разными данными и одинаковыми title, то ничего не выйдет. Нужно более точно строить запрос

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT можно только указать либо перечень полей нужных. Либо просто * поставь.